# WCF universal contract and UsernameToken

Tags: c#, wcf, security, soap

I have a self hosted soap server using WSHttpBinding. Additionally to some operations it also provides a universal contract interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://myns")]
public interface IGenericService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
    Message ProcessMessage(Message message);
}
```

The host should use an own UserNamePasswordValidator. I set it up like that:

```
ServiceCredentials servCredBehav = new ServiceCredentials();
servCredBehav.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode   = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
servCredBehav.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator  = new MyUserNamePasswordValidator();
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(servCredBehav);

WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Name = "WS_SOAP_12";
...
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

This is the (cleaned) validator:

```
public class MyUserNamePasswordValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName != "test" && password != "test123")
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid user name or incorrect password");
    } 
}
```

This works fine when I create a proxy using visual studio and call GetData like this:

```
using (GenericService12Https.GenericServiceClient bla = new GenericService12Https.GenericServiceClient())
{
    bla.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
    bla.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test123";

    bla.Open();
    string s = bla.GetData(5);
}
```

The problem occurs when I access this soap service with a low level approach like HttpWebRequest and directly send an xml to it so that ProcessMessage() gets called.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="uuid-412594ae-2641-4b2f-8458-631e17940108-1">
                <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test123</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:MessageID>...</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To>https://localhost:44301/Receiver.svc</wsa:To>
        <wsa:Action>...</wsa:Action>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <Dummy/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The server returns a HTTP 500 error with that content (Original error in German, this via Google Translate):

> The message could not be processed . Probable cause : The action " ...
>   " is wrong , the message contains an invalid or expired security
>   context token or between bonds is a conflict . The security context
>   token would be invalid if the service would have the channel
>   terminated due to inactivity . Increase the receive timeout for the
>   binding of the service endpoint to prevent the service terminates idle
>   sessions prematurely.

Either I use

```
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
```

then I can manually check credentials in ProcessMessage() but GetData() can be accessed unauthorized or

```
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

so that GetData() works as expected but ProcessMessage() is never called.

Any suggestions on how to enable Username/Password verification for all operations and the universal contract?
Btw. I can not alter the xml header as they come from a foreign system.